# C, caching and real-time querying

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I have a large Mysql table with products prices, and my system make more than 50 query per seconds in this table. This table have not often updates.

Actually I connect on the mysql via ODBC to SELECT the price of each product like

```
SELECT price WHERE product_id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

So, there are any way to caching this table on the memory and query directly on the memory.

Best regards

Comment: Leave it to the database engine. It will cache it itself. Do not worry

Comment: How do you know it's not cached in memory anyway?